# Date time formats: October not correctly written in German

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, datetime

I created a time format in Drupal administration (admin/config/regional/date-time) with the following settings in EN/ DE:

```
DE: d. F Y -> 05. October 2016
EN: dS F Y -> 05th October 2016
```

The problem is that "October" is written in German like "Oktober" ("k" instead of "c"). The strange thing is that the translation works fine with every other month ("May" for example becomes "Mai" in German) but just the October is written wrong. This appears to be an issue no matter where the date field is rendered, in views or node detail page.

Additionally this seems to be an issue with the PHP date format as it the same problem when using date('d. F Y', $timestamp). Can anyone give me a hint how to solve this issue?

Comment: If I check google translate, 'Oktober' is the right German translation for 'October'. Anyways, if you still want to change the German translation, you can just go to translation interface in Configuration, search the string there and then correct the translation.

Comment: Yes, "Oktober" is the correct translation but the date format is giving "October". The translation is not from interface but from date format but I can really change the translation in interface translation. I do not get why it is like that but ok... thank you

Answer (score 1):

The name of the month can be change via interface translation - see comment of Drupaler